# What to do when I get “mysqld dead but subsys locked” in my amazon ec2 micro instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 micro instance that holds a WordPress site. Since yesterday, my mysql db keep crashing saying:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo service mysqld status
mysqld dead but subsys locked
```

I tried restarting the mysqld but after every 5 mins it keeps crashing with the same message - "Error establishing a database connection"

This is what my DB log file reads -

```
160123 05:44:41 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160123  5:44:43 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as process 7928 ...
160123  5:44:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Aborting    
160123  5:44:46 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete
160123 05:44:46 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

The common solution that found out there when I Googled for a solution for the issue - `mysqld dead but subsys locked`, is to create a swapfile. I did exactly as most of the solution suggest but since I'm not well versed with UNIX, I don't know what I have done is right or not.

I have a swap space of 1MB.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx /]$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1019452     613820     405632         76      19124      64348
-/+ buffers/cache:     530348     489104
Swap:      1048572      46604    1001968
```

[image]

Or, Is there any other solution for this issue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

You have only 1GB of RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`; it should not be more than, say, 50M.

What changes did you make to my.cnf?  There may be other things to decrease.  (Or you could get more RAM.)

**More**

If you have more than just MySQL in that 1GB, it may really be impractical to have such a tiny VM.  Either split into to VMs, one for MySQL and one for app, or get get a bigger VM.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set at 128M.

This is what my my.cnf reads:

`[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

Comment: (I think `free` is in KB, not Bytes; swap seems to be 1GB, not 1MB.)